# ¿Como insertar los 3 resultados?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Intento insertar en el DOM los resultados obtenidos pero soy incapaz.

Obtengo una `template` a la cual le voy metiendo la información con un bucle `for`, pero a la hora de insertar dicha información en el DOM, solo obtengo el último resultado.

He intentado hacerlo con insertBefore(), pero no me sale:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>016</title>
    <script src="js/016.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <template id="producto">
        <h2 class="prod"></h2>
        <img class="imagen">
        <p class="espec"></p>
    </template>

</body>
</html>
```

```
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    readFileJson();

})

function readFileJson(){
    fetch('json/016.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        getTemplate(data);
    });
}

function getTemplate(data){
    let tmp = document.querySelector('#producto');
    let dvt = document.createElement('div');
        dvt.className = 'product';
        dvt.innerHTML = tmp.innerHTML;


    for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++){
        dvt.querySelector('.prod').innerHTML = data[i].producto;
        dvt.querySelector('.imagen').setAttribute('src', data[i].img);
        dvt.querySelector('.espec').innerHTML = data[i].especificaciones;

        if(!document.querySelector('.product')){
            document.body.appendChild(dvt);
        } else {
            document.insertBefore(dvt, document.body.nextSibling);
        }
    }
}
```

```
[{
    "id":"0001",
    "producto":"NAKAMURA HB02-100",
    "denominacion":"LUMINARIA HIGH BAY (UFO) ALTA EFICIENCIA",
    "fecha_cierre":"15/03/2021",
    "fecha_arribo":"13/06/2021",
    "embarque":"Luminaria HIGH BAY (UFO) MAY-2020",
    "precio":"FOB 33,950",
    "especificaciones":["Potencia: 100 W","Dimmable: NO","Tensión: 100~277 VCA","Eficiencia: 150/160 Lm/W"],
    "img":"/imagenes/201922150722 - Cengo-ZHNSA 100-150-200-240.png"
},
{
    "id":"0002",
    "producto":"NAKAMURA HB01-100",
    "denominacion":"LUMINARIA HIGH BAY (UFO) ANTIDESLUMBRAMIENTO",
    "fecha_cierre":"15/03/2021",
    "fecha_arribo":"13/06/2021",
    "embarque":"Luminaria HIGH BAY (UFO) MAY-2020",
    "precio":"FOB 37,850",
    "especificaciones":["Potencia: 40 W","Dimmable: SI","Tensión: 100~277 VCA"],
    "img":"/imagenes/201915150715 - Cengo-ZHN.png"
},
{
    "id":"0003",
    "producto":"NAKAMURA NK-F-A60-6-E",
    "denominacion":"LAMPARA FILAMENTO A60 6W",
    "fecha_cierre":"31/03/2021",
    "fecha_arribo":"29/06/2021",
    "embarque":"Lámparas JUN-2020",
    "precio":"FOB 0,830",
    "especificaciones":["Potencia: 50 W","Dimmable: NO","Tensión: 100~298 VCA","Frecuencia: 60 Hz"],
    "img":"/imagenes/201925140725 - Enshine-Filament A 60 8w.png"
}]
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que solo estas creando un elemento `div` y le estas poniendo la información y con el `for` estas sobrescribiendo su información. Para solucionar esto solo mueve la creación del `div` dentro del ciclo `for`

```
    let tmp = document.querySelector('#producto');
    for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++){
        let dvt = document.createElement('div');
        dvt.className = 'product';
        dvt.innerHTML = tmp.innerHTML;

        dvt.querySelector('.prod').innerHTML = data[i].producto;
        dvt.querySelector('.imagen').setAttribute('src', data[i].img);
        dvt.querySelector('.espec').innerHTML = data[i].especificaciones;

        if(!document.querySelector('.product')){
            document.body.appendChild(dvt);
        } else {
            document.insertBefore(dvt, document.body.nextSibling);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Esto crearia varios `divs` al final del body y cada div tendra una copia modificada de los datos, para que coincida con los datos del array, hmmm... en un principio no parece mala opcion,  creo que podria funcionar.

Comment: @Riven por qué se crearían al final del body si se supone que se están añadiendo al templete?

Comment: a, cierto se me olvida que a lo que se apunta es a un `template`.

Comment: Perfecto, aunque creando un nuevo div en cada iteración el if/else sobra. Igualmente bien visto. muchas gracias.